# Time complexity of a Python Shelf

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, time-complexity, complexity-theory

A [shelf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) in Python is a dictionary that is stored in secondary memory (i.e. on disk).

What are the time complexities in this setting of:

1. fetching a value corresponding to a key, and
2. updating a value?

Do these operations each take constant time, like they do in an ordinary Python `dict`, or do they get slower as your shelf gets bigger?

I notice that it is stored in two separate files - one of them a dat file.
Is that some sort of a look up table to make it faster?

Comment: Related / duplicate-ish: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57739653/1709587 suggests that the complexity is O(1), and asks how this is achieved. It doesn't demonstrate convincingly that it really *is* O(1), though. In chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48019165#48019165), some [python] regulars speculate that the answer may differ between Python implementations, or even between the different implementations (`Shelf`, `BsdDbShelf`, `DbfilenameShelf`) within the `shelve` module. There's a lot to unpick; let's wait and see if an answerer can do a comprehensive job of it.

Comment: From a quick test in Ubuntu, I would say roughly O(log(n)): I have almost the same time difference between tables of size 10^4 and 10^5 and between 10^5 and 10^6 (just reading, writing is already done)